# Error while building Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, maven-3

I am new at Spring framework. I have Spring Tool Suite Version 3.1.0 installed with JDK 1.7 on my system.
Recently I imported into my IDE a pre-built Spring MVC project already working on another system. But when I am trying to build it, it is giving the following error :-

`Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'vdm'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5`

Moreover, when I check Maven's Lifecycycle Mapping, it shows :-

[image]

My Environment configuration is as :-

[image]

My pom.xml is :-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
  <groupId>com.engineersindia</groupId> 
  <artifactId>vdsc</artifactId> 
  <name>abc</name> 
  <packaging>war</packaging> 
  <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version> 
- <properties>
  <java-version>1.6</java-version> 
  <org.springframework-version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version> 
  <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version> 
  <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version> 
  </properties>
- <dependencies>
- <!--  Spring 
  --> 
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
  <version>${org.springframework-version}</version> 
- <exclusions>
- <!--  Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j 
  --> 
- <exclusion>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> 
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> 
  </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
  <version>${org.springframework-version}</version> 
  </dependency>
- <!--  AspectJ 
  --> 
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId> 
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId> 
  <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version> 
  </dependency>
- <!--  Logging 
  --> 
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
  <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId> 
  <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version> 
  <scope>runtime</scope> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> 
  <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version> 
  <scope>runtime</scope> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId> 
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> 
  <version>1.2.15</version> 
- <exclusions>
- <exclusion>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId> 
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId> 
  </exclusion>
- <exclusion>
  <groupId>javax.jms</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jms</artifactId> 
  </exclusion>
- <exclusion>
  <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId> 
  </exclusion>
- <exclusion>
  <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId> 
  </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
  <scope>runtime</scope> 
  </dependency>
- <!--  @Inject 
  --> 
- <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId> 
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId> 
  <version>1</version> 
  </dependency>
- <!--  Servlet 
  --> 
- <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> 
  <version>2.5</version> 
  <scope>provided</scope> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId> 
  <version>2.1</version> 
  <scope>provided</scope> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
  <version>1.2</version> 
  </dependency>
- <!--  Test 
  --> 
- <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId> 
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
  <version>4.7</version> 
  <scope>test</scope> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId> 
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId> 
  <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
  <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId> 
  <version>3.1.0.M2</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
  <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId> 
  <version>3.1.0.M2</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId> 
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId> 
  <version>1.4</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>displaytag</groupId> 
  <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId> 
  <version>1.2</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId> 
  <version>1.5.3</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> 
  <version>4.1.0.Final</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>cglib</groupId> 
  <artifactId>cglib</artifactId> 
  <version>2.2</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId> 
  <version>4.7.0</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>commons-digester</groupId> 
  <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId> 
  <version>2.1</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId> 
  <artifactId>groovy</artifactId> 
  <version>1.7.11</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId> 
  <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId> 
  <version>4.7.0</version> 
  </dependency>
- <dependency>
  <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId> 
  <artifactId>itext</artifactId> 
  <version>2.1.7</version> 
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
- <build>
- <plugins>
- <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
- <configuration>
  <source>${java-version}</source> 
  <target>${java-version}</target> 
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
- <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
- <configuration>
  <warName>abc</warName> 
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
- <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> 
- <executions>
- <execution>
  <id>install</id> 
  <phase>install</phase> 
- <goals>
  <goal>sources</goal> 
  </goals>
  </execution>
  </executions>
  </plugin>
- <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId> 
  <version>2.5</version> 
- <configuration>
  <encoding>UTF-8</encoding> 
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  </project>
```

Even when I am importing the project as a Maven Project, after retrieving listings, it giving the following errors :-

[image]

Comment: Maybe the original project was using a different Maven version. What happens if you create a new Project and copy all the files? (except the `pom.xml` and Eclipse files)

Comment: can you show your pom.xml file?

Comment: @madth3 I did that and the IDE is not recognising many API's and annotations.

Comment: @ILLA I have added my pom.xml.

Comment: Wondering if there could be some problem with the network as it saying "No marketplace entries found to handle maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the contents of the folder in following path.

```
C:\Users\{your computer user name}\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin\2.5
```

If you didn't find this folder or there is no content there then you must check the proxy configurations of the eclipse or you might be referencing to a wrong settings.xml file of maven.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: There are two file in the directory of 1 KB each namely:
 m2e-lastUpdated.properties and m2e-lastUpdated.properties.
Plus while I am trying to import the project as a Maven Project, and it is retrieving listings, a new file od 0 KB is being created and removed again and again.

Comment: That is the problem your plugin is not getting downloaded from the maven repository. Have you checked your maven configurations in the eclipse? Is there a settings.xml file referenced for maven? Also check the proxy settings of eclipse if you are behind a proxy server.

Comment: There is no settings.xml file in user's .m2 directory. Only repository folder is there.

Comment: And also check the configuration for the same in your eclipse.

Go to :: Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings

And then check the path displayed in Local Repository.

Also check your proxy configurations.

Comment: Its saying "User settings file doesn't exist" with an exclamatory sign. And I am sorry but can you elaborate a little further on how to check proxy settings.

Comment: can you see any path in the Local Repository disabled text box right there?

Comment: Yes, I am behind a prxy network.
The following is written in the lastupdated.properties files
"default-http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1351568152535
http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins\:maven-dependency-plugin\:pom\:2.1 from/to central (http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)\: connection timed out to http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom"
So can we now pin-point the problem to proxy?

Comment: Ya.. So now the real culprit is proxy. You can open Window > Preferences and type "proxy" in the filter text box on the left-top area. Then you can see the setting "Network Connections" in the general menu. There you need to select Active Provider as Manual and then provide proper IP address and port number of your proxy. And if the proxy is password protected then you also need to specify the Username and password.

Comment: As I see in the Network Connections, the IDE is already picking up my proxy settings from the native system.

Comment: Would you please tell me what all files should be there in a particular plugin's folder, for eg say "C:\Users\User1\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-compiler-plugin\2.3.2" after all the dependencies have been resolved.

Comment: Okay. I need to consult our IT personnel for our proxy details. I'll get to that.

Comment: maven-resources-plugin-2.3.jar
maven-resources-plugin-2.3.jar.sha1
maven-resources-plugin-2.3.pom
maven-resources-plugin-2.3.pom.sha1

Comment: what if I manually download and put the files in the plugins directory from the online repository http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/ for the time being?