# Error while building Spring MVC project

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, maven-3, ubuntu-10.04

I've download Eclipse STS 3.2.0 and installed Apache Tomcat 7, JDK 6 and Maven 3.0.4, then tried to create a new Spring MVC empty project using Eclipse.

Yet I always get this error when I try to run this 'empty' project even though I didn't write even a single line of code in it, all of the code inside it is auto-generated using Eclipse

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'GoodProjectSTS'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies  could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources- plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact  descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies  could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

When I check if Maven is installed and working using

```
mvn --version
```

I get the following in output

```
The program 'mvn' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install maven2
```

I have edited /etc/enivronment and made sure that the following is in inside it:

```
JAVA_HOME=”/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun”
M3_HOME=”/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.2″
MAVEN_HOME=”/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.2″
M3=”/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.2/bin”
```

yet I still get the same error when I type mvn -version

So can someone please tell me what I am missing here? or how I can resolve this problem and get the empty application to run?

**NOTE: I am running the above under Ubuntu 10.04**

**Note 2: I tried uninstalling maven then re-installing using instructions in http://lukieb.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/installing-maven-3-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-server/ but with no success (same errors appeared), and still mvn -version returns error**

Thanks

Comment: have you add $MAVEN_HOME/bin to the PATH?

Comment: May be this post will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132551/error-while-building-spring-mvc-application

Comment: @TerryMa I've added MAVEN_HOME as shown in the question, shall I add /bin to the end?

Comment: @Tom I don't have such mapping screen like that shown in the question even though I am using almost the same STS version, I guess may be this is because I am using the Linux copy under Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0):

pls check in following directory if the jar is available
{home directory}.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin\2.5
Also, try to download the jar manually and add it to your build in eclipse and check if the same error occurs

Download location:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5

Comment: thanks a lot, but I've just checked this path and found maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar with size 36 KB under the folder you mentioned. On the other hand I tried following the link you provided me to re-download and override the jar file, but it give me 404 when trying to download the file